# Restful API delete error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a pretty standard restful API with the usual functions.  I have tested the API and most things work.  For instance to get a list of products in my external system I do

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://someurl/api/v1/product');
$output = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

I am having issues with the delete function however.  Where I list my products, within the loop I have

```
<a href="{{ route('products.destroy', $products->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" data-method="delete" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Delete
</a>
```

I have the delete route on the form open as well. So this calls the following function

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    if ($user = Sentinel::getUser())
    {
        $deleteProduct = APIHelper::deleteProduct($id);
    }
}
```

If I output the id variable it is correct.  This in turn calls the following

```
public static function deleteProduct($id)
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $req = $client->request('DELETE', 'https://someurl/api/v1/product/'.$id);

    $output = $req->getBody()->getContents();

    return $output;
}
```

This however returns the following error

> Client error: `DELETE https://someurl/api/v1/product/2` resulted in a
>   `403 Forbidden` response:

Is there any reason why I may be getting this response?  As I say, the API is working with pretty much everything besides the delete.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't really know why you get a 403, but you if-statement inside your destroy is a bit weird. I'd change it to `if (Sentinel::getUser())` since you don't use the `$user` anywhere.

Comment: As mentioned @Loek, the if statement will always execute as the assignment statement will always return true.

Comment: Thanks, was going to make use of user at some point.  Removed for now

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Are you making an API that calls another API?

Comment: So why add the statement in the first place then? We're going off topic here though, let's help OP find his 403 error

Comment: The API is calling another API, I am afraid the error is coming from the other one.

Comment: Sorry, I have 2 laravel systems that are completely separate but on the same server.  They have to be separate systems for a reason.  To allow system A to interact with System B I am building an API within System B.  Everything seems to work besides the delete route.

Comment: I have found a way to get into the destroy method, if I use post instead of delete.  Is it ok using post to actually delete an Object?

Comment: Try doing a `php artisan route:list` on the API application and see what HTTP Methods are exposed and what Actions they are associated with.
If the delete action is only accessible from the POST method then you just use POST, not an issue.

Comment: Did check that.  The routes are exposed as they should be

Comment: May have found the problem.  Looks like my vhost is only accepting get and post request.  Will try altering this